# How do I write to a file and print to a terminal concurrently in Unix?

Tags: bash, file-io, terminal, unix, macports

I have a little bash function to log my Macports outputs to a file (since installs often spew little tidbits that are easy to lose in terminal noise), then I just cat the file to the terminal:

```
function porti {
    command sudo port install $@ >> $1.log 2>&1; cat $1.log
}
```

*Is there a way to do this concurrently?*

**BTW** I pass $@ to install but only $1 for the file name so that I can do something like:

```
porti git-gore +bash_completion
```

and only get the file *git-core.log* however someone else might prefer to include variants in the file name...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual solution is to use **tee(1)**:

```
sudo port install $@ 2>&1 | tee -a $1.log
```

should do what you want

Comment: You crazy Unix people amaze me! How did you know about the command tee(1)?

Comment: tee is part of the standard shellutils GNU package of about 2 dozen random commands that are useful in shell scripts, and which have been around for decades